# Error: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useState is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, frontend, vercel

i have this problem programming in Next.js 13. I really appreciate any help or suggestion =), here are the files:

## typingtext.tsx

```
import React from "react";

export function useTypedText(text: string, speed: number, delayTime?: number) {
  const [textState, setTextState] = React.useState("")
  const chars = text.split("")
  let interval = speed

  if(textState.length === 0 && delayTime)
    interval = speed + delayTime

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setTextState((prevText) => {
        if (prevText.length !== chars.length) {
          const newText = prevText.concat(chars[prevText.length])
          return newText
        }
        return prevText
      })
    }, interval)
    return () => clearTimeout(timer)
  })

  return textState
}
```

## mainheader.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTypedText }  from '../typingtext';

export function VMainHeader() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        {useTypedText("Hello everyone!", 50)}
        <br/>
        {useTypedText("I'm Diego.", 50, 200)}
      </h1>
      <h2>
        {useTypedText("Welcome", 30, 350)}
      </h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

## home.tsx

```
import React from "react"
import { VMainHeader } from "./mainheader"
export default function VHome(){
  return(
    <div>
      <VMainHeader />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Im expecting know what happening, because i already try with

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
```

in the typingtext.tsx file but it doesn't work

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine. What versions of react are you using? Can you share a snippet of your `package.json` with the React stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i already fix this error so im writing now this to help people like me because i think that is a new feature of Next.js 13 or idk, im noob in Next xD.

It works for me when i wrote **"use client"** into the top of my **mainheader.tsx** file:

```
"use client"
import React from 'react';
import { useTypedText }  from '../typingtext';

export function VMainHeader() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        {useTypedText("Hello everyone!", 50)}
        <br/>
        {useTypedText("I'm Diego.", 50, 200)}
      </h1>
      <h2>
        {useTypedText("Welcome", 30, 350)}
      </h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Thank you very much to those who tried to help me <3.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you try to create a custom hook `useTypedText`. Don't use in the return.
You probably want to change it to a component instead, rename it to TypedText and you need to at least wrap the state in framgent.

```js
return <>{textState}</>
```